# Tower of strings

Tags: code-golf, string, number

Given a string of text, output it as a 'tower'.

Each slice of the string (of the form `0:n`) is repeated `5*n` times, so the first character is repeated 5 times, then the first and the second 10 times, etc.

#### Examples:

```
'hello' ->

['h']  
['h']  
['h']  
['h']  
['h']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  


'cat' ->

['c']  
['c']  
['c']  
['c']  
['c']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']  
['c', 'a', 't']
```

#### Rules:

You can output each layer as a list of characters or just a string of them joined together.

Comment: welcome to PPCG! Nice challenge.

Comment: I tried to clean up the formatting and explain the challenge a little bit better. Did I understand the challenge right?

Comment: Can we take the input as a list of characters ?

Comment: Can we output a 2D-array of strings like so: `[["c","c","c","c","c"],["ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca"],...]`?

Comment: Are outputs with leading or trailing newlines acceptable? Can we assume inputs do not contain newlines?

Comment: I assume that an empty string will display a single white space or no characters?

Comment: Does it need to actually print, or just return the output?

Comment: It has to print

Answer (score 12):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
function(s)substring(s,1,rep(x<-1:nchar(s),x*5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYs7g0qbikKDMvXaNYx1CnKLVAo8JG19AqLzkjsQgorVOhZaqp@T9NQykjNScnX0mTC8hMTixR0vwPAA)

Returns a list of strings.

Comment: I had missed the obvious golf here! nice solution I tried different approaches but so far all are far longer than this.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ηā5*ÅΓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3PYjjaZah1vPTf7/PyM1JycfAA)

Returns a list of string.

**Explanation**

```
     ÅΓ # Run-length decode...
η       # ... the prefixes of the input
 ā5*и   # ... with the length range multiplied by 5 -- [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for noticing that ! I should not golf in the morning without a coffee first :-(

Comment: Using run length decoding saves 3 bytes: [`ηā5*ÅΓ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3PYjjaZah1vPTf7/PyM1JycfAA)

Comment: @Adnan Brilliant, thanks ! I think it deserves its own answer though, you've reduced the byte count by 33%...
I'll revert to my original solution if you decide to post it yourself.

Comment: Nice one, I had `ηvyg5*Fy=` for 8.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
f""=[]
f s=f(init s)++(s<$s<*[1..5])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P01JyTY6litNodg2TSMzL7NEoVhTW1uj2Eal2EYr2lBPzzRW839uYmaegq1CbmKBr0JBaUlwSZFPnoKKQpqCUgbQkHyl/wA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
［³５×＊Ｐ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNCJUIzJXVGRjE1JUQ3JXVGRjBBJXVGRjMw,i=JTIyaGVsbG8lMjI_,v=6)

Explanation:

```
[      for each prefix
 ³5×     1-indexed counter * 5
    *    repeat the prefix vertically that many times
     P   and print that
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
äï▄;♫├W^
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=848bdc3b0ec3575e&i=hello&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
|[F for each prefix of the input
  i^5*  5*(i+1) where i is the iteration index
  DQ    that many times, peek and print to output
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C[F%09for+each+prefix+of+the+input%0A++i%5E5*%095*%28i%2B1%29+where+i+is+the+iteration+index%0A++DQ%09that+many+times,+peek+and+print+to+output&i=hello&a=1)

Answer (score 6):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 29 bytes (27 tokens)

```
For(A,1,length(Ans
For(B,1,5A
Disp sub(Ans,1,A
End
End
```

Explanation:

```
For(A,1,length(Ans # 9 bytes, 8 tokens: for A from 1 to the length of the string
For(B,1,5A         # 8 bytes, 8 tokens:  5*A times
Disp sub(Ans,1,A   # 9 bytes, 8 tokens:   Print the first A characters of the string 
End                # 2 bytes, 2 tokens:  end loop
End                # 1 byte,  1 token:  end loop
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 15 bytes

```
.
$.>`*5*$($>`¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F@PS0XPLkHLVEtFQ8Uu4dC2//8zUnNy8rmSE0sA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.
```

Match each character in the string.

```
$.>`*5*$($>`¶
```

`` $` `` is the prefix of the match. Retina then provides two modifiers, `>` modifies it to be in the context of the string between successive matches, while `.` takes the length. We therefore start with the prefix of the suffix, which is equivalent to the match including its prefix. This saves 2 bytes over using overlapping matches. The `$(` then concatenates that with a newline, the `5*` repeats it, and then the `` $.>` `` repeats it a further number of times given by its length.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
a₀ᶠ⟨gj₎{l×₅}⟩ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy//9h4oKA4bag4p@oZ2rigo57bMOX4oKFfeKfqeG1kGP//yJjYXQi/1o)

The final `c` can be removed if OP replies positively to the question about outputting 2D arrays.

Answer (score 6):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix),  <s>44</s>  40 bytes

```
i.!?@UBqwW_#/>u...;B^...?qo;;q*n5;oN/./)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z9TT9HeIdSpsDw8XlnfrlRPT8/aKQ5I2hfmW1sXauWZWuf76evpa/7/75Gak5MPAA)

This still has a lot of no-ops, but it is a little better than before.

As a very brief description, a character is grabbed from input and tested for EOI (-1), halt if it is.  The stack is then reversed.  Get the number of items on the stack and multiple by -5.  Drop that to the bottom of the stack and clean up.  Loop through the stack, printing, until a negative number.  Print newline, increment the number, if 0 drop the zero, reverse stack and start from input again, otherwise loop through the stack, printing, until a negative number ... ad nauseum

Cubified it looks like

```
      i . !
      ? @ U
      B q w
W _ # / > u . . . ; B ^
. . . ? q o ; ; q * n 5
; o N / . / ) . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

[Watch it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgaSAuICEKICAgICAgPyBAIFUKICAgICAgQiBxIHcKVyBfICMgLyA+IHUgLiAuIC4gOyBCIF4KLiAuIC4gPyBxIG8gOyA7IHEgKiBuIDUKOyBvIE4gLyAuIC8gKSAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4=&input=c3RlcAo=&speed=20)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
¹Ƥx'J×5Ɗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzmNLKtS9Dk83Pdb1/3B75P//GUCJfAA)

```
J×5x'@¹Ƥ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r8HTTCnWHQzuPLfl/uD3y//8MoHg@AA)

```
¹Ƥx'Jx'5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzmNLKtS9KtRN/x9uj/z/PwMonA8A)

This is likely golfable.

Comment: A slightly different 8 is `+\ẋ"Jx5Ẏ`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <strike>48</strike> 46 bytes

(thanks @redundancy)

Edit: The author clarified and this answer is now not valid, but I will leave it here unchanged.

Returns an array of multi-line strings.

```
s=>[...s].map(c=>(q+=c).repeat(5*++i),i=q=`
`)
```

## Try it

```js
f = s=>[...s].map(c=>(q+=c).repeat(5*++i),i=q=`
`);

console.log( f("hello").join`` );
```

## Potential strategy:

It didn't help me much, but maybe someone can use this:

The number of characters at (0-indexed) line `i` is `floor(sqrt(2/5*i+1/4)+1/2)`, which is golfed in JavaScript as `(.4*i+.25)**.5+.5|0`.

For a string of length `n`, there are `n*(n+1)*5/2` lines.

Perhaps:
`s=>{for(i=0;(n=(.4*i+++.25)**.5+.5|0)<=s.length;)console.log(s.slice(0,n))}`

Comment: Assuming your output format is valid according to the challenge, you can save 2 bytes as demonstrated here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoAgDADA3Y9YRLs51o8YEwhWxSBFIX4fvfVO@9rsHp/KEGXlulHNNM2ImBe8bAJHE9yanMKHE9sCY6e1V72nm0xjVHUSswTGIDts0B4cgrQKT/HR/P0B "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

Thanks to *ovs* for saving 2 bytes!

#### Code

```python
f=lambda x:[*x]and f(x[:-1])+[x]*5*len(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocIqWqsiNjEvRSFNoyLaStcwVlM7uiJWy1QrJzVPo0Lzf0FRZl6JRpqGUnJiiZKm5n8A)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
f s=do n<-[1..length s];take n s<$[1..n*5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2DYlXyHPRjfaUE8vJzUvvSRDoTjWuiQxO1UhT6HYRgUknqdlGvs/NzEzT8FWITexwDdeoaC0JLikyCdPQUUhTUEpObFE6T8A)

Sadly `inits` requires `import Data.List`, so

```
import Data.List
((<$)<*>(>>[1..5])=<<).inits
```

with its 45 bytes is longer.

Edit: -1 byte thanks to @BWO.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｆ⊕ＬθＥ×⁵ι…θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxDoAgDADAr3RsExydfIGJJA5@gEAVkgKCxO/XeNP56LqvTlTP2gHX4jtnLoMDblyuEbEREew9lYHW3XikzA/OBhIZsFUCtv9Ei2pkkarTKx8) Link is to verbose version of code. Output includes 0 repetitions of the zero-length substring. Explanation:

```
   θ          Input string
  Ｌ           Length
 ⊕            Incremented
Ｆ             Loop over implicit range
      ⁵       Literal 5
       ι      Current index
     ×        Multiply
    Ｅ         Map over implicit range
         θ    Input string
          ι   Current index
        …     Chop to length
              Implicitly print each string on its own line
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ΣzoR*5Nḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziqvwgLVO/hzsW////Xyk5sUQJAA)

#### Explanation

```
Σz(R*5)Nḣ  -- example input: "ab"
        ḣ  -- non-empty prefixes: ["a","ab"]
 z(   )N   -- zip with [1..]
    *5     -- | multiply by 5
   R       -- | replicate
           -- : [["a","a","a","a","a"],["ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab"]]
Σ          -- concat: ["a","a","a","a","a","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab","ab"]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 67 bytes

```c
i,j;f(char*s){for(i=0;s[i++];)for(j=5*i;j--;)printf("%.*s\n",i,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczBCoMwEATQu1@xCEI2JqUeelrsj1gP6ULsBpqWpHgRvz2a3t7MwLBdmEsRE8grfrmkM27@k5SMV8qT9P1MWHMYb1ooWEv4TRJ/XrXdRedHbI2YjLSXs4S3k6gqXFrY1D/Q@vSKsDUA4lUd7gPCX@s0zEjNXop78gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>46</s> 42 bytes

```ruby
->s{(1..s.size).map{|i|puts [s[0,i]]*i*5}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664WsNQT69YrzizKlVTLzexoLoms6agtKRYIbo42kAnMzZWK1PLtLb2P1hMKSM1JydfQddOiSstGsJRiuUCSXFB5JMTS2CyQKZS7H8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>40</s> <s>20</s> 25 bytes

<sup>Score cut in half thanks to mazzy</sup>
<sup>+5 bytes thanks to AdmBorkBork pointing out the specs</sup>

```powershell
$args|%{,($s+=$_)*5*++$i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9XyWxKL24RrVaR0OlWNtWJV5Ty1RLW1sls/Z/LReXCkhlPlCdEpihxKUG1OUAZv8HAA)

Takes input via splatting. Works by building the string by adding the next character to itself, converts it to a one element array, and then repeats it `5*i` times.

Comment: `param` is very expensive. [Try to avoid it](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9XyWxKL24RrVaR0OlWNtWJV5Ty7T2fy0XlwpIUT5QiRKYocSlBtTgAGb/BwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Dang, trying to save the index instead of the char itself led me astray. Thanks.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Ha ha, whoops. Should be fixed now

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
f"G@:)@5*1X"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P03J3cFK08FUyzBC6f9/9YzUnJx89f8A)

```
f               % Get the indices of input i.e. range 1 to length(input)
 "              % For loop over that
   G            % Push input string
    @           % Push current loop index
     :          % Range 1 to that
      )         % Index at those positions (substring 1 to i)
       @5*      % Multiply loop index by 5
          1X"   % Repeat the substring that many times rowwise
                % Results collect on the stack and are 
                %  implicitly output at the end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 17 bytes

```
òïç$îî/6Ä
Hl$xòxú
```

Expects inputs without newlines, and outputs with superfluous leading newlines.

I can remove this entry if input/output violates the challenge spec.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P92///DssOvw6ckw67Dri82w4QKSGwkeMOyeMO6//9oZWxsbw)

#### 21 bytes

```
òïç$îî/6Ä
Hl$xòxíîî/ò
```

Expects inputs without newlines, but outputs with only one leading and trailing newline.

### Explanation

Differing substrings are separated with two consecutive newlines so that
linewise duplication only applies to lines matching the regex `$\n\n`.

When the duplication command (`Ä`) is supplied a count, e.g. `6Ä`, (I think) it
deletes the current line before pasting `n` times, thus only appearing to append `n - 1` copies.

```
ò         | recursively...
 ï        | . append newline
  ç       | . globally search lines matching...
   $îî    | . . compressed version of $\n\n regex
      /6Ä | . . duplicate to create 6 copies
H         | . go to first line
 l        | . move cursor right 1 char
          | . . if current line is 1 char long, errors out of recursion
  $x      | . delete 1 char from end of current line
    ò     | ...end
     x    | delete extra 1-char substring
      ú   | sort so that newlines rise to top
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{↑(5×⍳≢⍵)/,\⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR20QN08PTH/VuftS56FHvVk19nRggVfs/7VHbhEe9fY/6pnr6P@pqPrTeGKgUyAsOcgaSIR6ewf/TFNRLUotL1AE)

My first apl post so please let me know if you have any suggestions

### How it works:

```apl
{↑(5×⍳≢⍵)/,\⍵}
          ,\⍵  - Prefixes of the input
         /      - Repeated
     ⍳≢⍵        - By a list of indices the same length as the input
   5×           - Times 5
 ↑              - Separate into rows
```

Comment: `↑` isn't really *Separate into rows* but rather *Combine [list of lists] into rows [of a matrix]*, or more technically *Increase rank at the expense of depth*.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wenyan](https://github.com/LingDong-/wenyan-lang), <s>350</s> <s>326</s> 308 bytes

```
吾有一術名之曰「A」欲行是術必先得一言曰「B」是術曰有數零名之曰「C」吾有一言名之曰「D」凡「B」中之「E」加五於「C」昔之「C」者今其是矣加「E」於「D」昔之「D」者今其是矣為是「C」遍夫「D」書之云云云云是謂「A」之術也
```

[IDE](http://wenyan-lang.lingdong.works/ide.html)

Just seen this programming language on GitHub, so I'll have a try. There is no equivalent for "process.argv", so I have to write this as a function, but then the boilerplate `吾有一術名之曰「X」欲行是術必先得一言曰「X」乃行是術曰...是謂「X」之術也` itself (114 bytes) is just too long.

Each variable has to be at least 7 bytes (the brackets themselves take 6 bytes), and a string takes `12 bytes + length of string` to achieve. Of course I can trivially put something like ``` 施「eval」於「「a=>[...a].map(_=>(a.slice(0,++i)+'\\n').repeat(i*5),i=0).join``」」 ``` (91 bytes) but that's boring (why not use JavaScript then?)

#### Explanation

```
function A(B) {
 var C = 0, D = "";
 for (var E of B) {
  C = C + 5;
  D = D + E;
  for (var i = 0; i < C; i++)
   console.log(D);
 }
}
```

#### 326->308 `乃行` before `是術曰` is optional so it's removed, and `吾有一言曰「D」` is replaced by `夫「D」` to recall the variable.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

*-3 bytes from @Shaggy*

```
£¯°Y +R pY*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9DiQ@sPbYhU0A5SKIjUMv3/XykjNScnXwkA)

Comment: [12 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=o6+wWSArUiBwWSo1&input=ImNhdCI=) (including a small fix)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{(1..*X*5)RZxx[\~] .comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1rDUE9PK0LLVDMoqqIiOqYuVkEvOT83qfZ/moaSoZGSpp2dXnFipfV/AA)

Anonymous code block that returns a list of list of strings.

If you want it as a 1D array, you can append `flat` in front like so:

```perl6
{flat (1..*X*5)RZxx[\~] .comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzotJ7FEQcNQT08rQstUMyiqoiI6pi5WQS85Pzep9n@ahpKhkbGSpp2dXnFipfV/AA)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                       }  # Anonymous code block
                   .comb   # Split the string into a list of characters
              [\~]         # Triangular reduce the list of characters with the concatenate operator
          RZxx             # Multiply each list by:
 (1..*X*5)                 # A sequence of 5,10,15 etc.
```

Alternatively,

```perl6
{($+=5)xx*RZxx[\~] .comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pDRdvWVLOiQisoqqIiOqYuVkEvOT83qfZ/moaSoZGxkqadnV5xYqX1fwA)

Also works for the same amount of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 29 bytes

```perl
map{say}($x.=$_)x($y+=5)for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r1Jpq1Jhq6Rk/T83saC6OLGyVkOlQs9WJV6zQkOlUtvWVDMtv8jB7f//jNScnHyu5MSSf/kFJZn5ecX/dXPc/uv6muoZGBoAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 10 bytes

Awaiting confirmation as to whether the output format is acceptable (+2 bytes if not).

```
å+ £T±5 ÇX
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5Ssgo1SxNSDHWA==&input=ImNhdCIKLVE=)

Comment: Output looks reasonable to me, nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>120</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> 89 bytes

```java
s->{for(int j=1,i=1;i<=s.length();i+=++j>i*5?j=1:0)System.out.println(s.substring(0,i));}
```

-28 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY87DsIwDEB3TmF1SihEMLAQAisLLIyIIYQALiFFtYuEUM9eQunIYsnf91zYpx0Xp1vrgiWCjcUI7wEARvbV2ToP228K8CzxBE7suMJ4AZI6VZtBCsSW0cEWIhhoabx8n8tKpH0ozHSEZqpxYUgFHy98FVJjbvK8WOJwtkoD84ncvYj9XZU1q0c6ziEKUlQfqUOJyQil1E2rv7BHfQwJ1jM7p3tS7rX2B7DypxuVE9nah1BmnSrAH0zf6Wad5ax/qmk/)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                      // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(int j=1,            //  Repeat-integer, starting at 1
      i=1;i<=s.length()   //  Loop `i` in the range [1,length_input]
      ;                   //    After every iteration:
       i+=++j>i*5?        //     Increase `j` by 1 first with `++j`
                          //     If `j` is now larger than `i` multiplied by 5:
           j=1            //      Increase `i` by 1, and reset `j` to 1
          :               //     Else:
           0)             //      Leave `i` the same by increasing it with 0
    System.out.println(   //   Print with trailing newline:
      s.substring(0,i));} //    The prefix of size `i`
```

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY0xb8IwFIT3/IonJpuABUOXJqYDMxNj1cGYJDzXsSO/Z6QK5benbjqd7r7TnTNPs3f37wXHKSYGV7zKjF71OVjGGNS2qaw3RHAxGOBVAUz55tECseEiz4h3GAsTV04Yhs8vMGkguVYBzjFQHrvU/tMT9KAX2p9efUwCAwPq487pY4OtJuW7MPBDyAZr7eq6xe3bx@G9FqUg5fWHuBtVzKymssU@CFKUb7Qui8MOpWzmpVl/e2Ws7SYWG2t4I//CuZqXXw): `s->{for(int i=1,j=1;i<=s.length();i+=j++<i*5?0:+(j=1))System.out.println(s.substring(0,i));}`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! And I've been able to golf 2 more bytes by changing using `>=` and `?j=1:0` instead of `<` and `?0:+(j=1)`.

Comment: Good! I was trying to get rid of it, but I kept having compilation issues. Didn't think about reverting the condition. Well done! ;)

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 48 bytes

```forth
: f 1+ 1 do i 5 * 0 do dup j type cr loop loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRhqKxgqpOQrZCqYKmgpGICYKaUFClkKJZUFqQrJRQo5@fkFEML6f7GSQkZqTk6@kkLafwA)

#### Explanation

1. Loop from 1 to string-length
2. for each iteration:

   1. Loop (5 * loop index) times
   2. Print string from beginning to outer loop index

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                \ start a new word definiton
  1+ 1             \ set up to the loop paramers from 1 to str-length
  do               \ start a counted loop
    i 5 * 0 do     \ start a second counted loop from 0 to 5*index - 1
      dup j        \ duplicate the string address and set the length to the outer index
      type         \ print character from start of string to loop index
      cr           \ output a newline
    loop           \ end inner counted loop
  loop             \ end outer counted loop
;                  \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 76 bytes

```
s=>{for(i=1;i<=s.length;i++)for(j=0;j<5*i;j++)console.log(s.substring(0,i))}
```

```js
f=s=>{for(i=1;i<=s.length;i++)for(j=0;j<5*i;j++)console.log(s.substring(0,i))}

f("cat")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG.

Comment: `i=1;i<=s.length;i++` can be `i=0;++i<=s.length;`.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 40 bytes

```
++++++++++>,[>>+++++[<<[<]>[.>]>>+<-]<,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw7sdKLt7MCsaBubaJtYu2g9u1igiI1urI1O7P//Gak5OfkA)

```
[Tape: 10 (newline), [characters], 0, rowcounter]

++++++++++> 10 (newline)
,[          for each input character
  >>+++++     add 5 to number of rows
  [           for each row
    <<[<]       go to start
    >[.>]       print newline and all previous characters
    >>+         add 1 to next rowcounter cell
    <-          decrement current rowcounter cell
  ]
  <,          input next character
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```ruby
f=->s{s[0]?f[s.chop]+[s]*s.size*5:[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1664ujjaINY@LbpYLzkjvyBWO7o4VqtYrzizKlXL1Co6tvZ/QWlJsUJatFJGak5OvlIsF4yfnFiiFPsfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda a:[a[:i]for i in range(len(a)+1)for j in' '*5*i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg7DoAgDADQqzQsfJyMcSHxJMhQI0gNFkNYPD3qG9/9tFR46nFZe8Zr2xHQOnSWfCwVCIihIh9B5cAK9TDq/8/vJUgzG/L9rsRNRSVSyLkIrfsL)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
WẋL×5ƊƊƤẎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/84a5un8PTTY91AeGSh7v6/h9uj/z/PwMomw8A)

-2 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/84a5un8PTTY91AeGSh7v6/h9uj/z/PwMomw8A).

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 47 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$s=[repeatn(5*i)c\\c<-s&i<-[1..]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCsIwEIDhvU8RsFgVUnBwazYdBLeOaYaQpvUguZTkKvjyngUHx//jd8Fb5JjGNXgRLSBDXFIm0dN4w1dVF6WzX7wlPFxOcHTD4DpZ9tBJfW5bY7gnm6naiUIZcBZK6ObpQ0iN2XBa0REk3Liu1D9/M3/cFOxcWN4ffH2jjeDKFw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 30 bytes

```
{k:c(k)*5*count(k)}on prefixes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctBCoMwEEbhvaf4ySrjvptAwauEcUJF64gzQov17GkK3b3F93wa37Ug3es5J44z9bee9Vi95aUrtl3K9BKrLuaN4QQbEp55i3o4oZkS2QgfFN1ZcA3mmrvuN8TA2QP9@yHLooHqFw)

Returns a list of list of characters. If that is not acceptable, the following also works:

### Tidy, 37 bytes

```
{k:out on c(k)*5*count(k)}on prefixes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCoQwDEbhvaf46ap176Yw4FUkplgUM5gII@rZa4XZfTye5fEoCfFTzjnKbpAV5OfQdi3JvlrlXdN345R/rMVYrd44QYqI5EkDLiTZiHH3ajI0zTt5R4O58PfEyyIulAc)

### Explanation

```
{k:c(k)*5*count(k)}on prefixes
{k:               }on prefixes     over each prefix k:
   c(k)                              the singleton list k
       *5                            ...repeated 5 times
         *count(k)                   ...repeated by the number of elements in the prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda s:s and f(s[:-1])+(s+'\n')*len(s)*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlghMS9FIU2jONpK1zBWU1ujWFs9Jk9dUysnNU@jWFPL9H9BUWZeCVCFenJiibom138A)

Comment: You can return as a list of strings for [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlghMS9FIU2jONpK1zBWUzu6OFbLVCsnNU@jWDO/KDr2f0FRZl4JUIF6cmKJuibXfwA "Python 2 – Try It Online"). Or if do input and output as a list of characters,  [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoMwDADAva/wFpsCEkhdIvUlwOAWIoyCE@EsfX3KzZd/ZU861vCea@TzszKYN2BdIaBNvhsWek62NK8mbopGNaQLBETh5IzO9UcSbe8cxQq6LxdHRP4BkC/RgkL1Dw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## bash, 89 bytes (or 158 bytes for extra complex output shown as exemple)

version 1: 89 bytes (output cat as lines with: c  ca   cat )

```
read a;for i in $(seq 1 ${#a});do for c in $(seq 1 $((i*5)));do echo "${a:0:i}";done;done
```

version 2 : 158 bytes ( output cat as lines with : ['c']  ['c', 'a']  ['c', 'a', 't'] )

```
read a;for i in $(seq 1 ${#a});do for c in $(seq 1 $((i*5)));do printf "[$(for j in $(seq 1 $i);do printf ", '${a:j-1:1}'";done)]\n";done;done|sed -e 's/, //'
```

Comment: @whalalalalalala-chen : I try to respect the output given in the question... as it is unclear what output would be acceptable otherwise (if it could be : c ca  cat, without the '[' ']' and "'" , then the answer can be much shorter!)

Answer (score 0):

## awk, 74 bytes  (or 144 for the extra complex output shown in question)

version 1, 74 bytes: that the question seems to allow (each lines looking like:  c  ca  cat )

```
{for(c=1;c<=length($1);c++)for(n=1;n<=c*5;n++){print substr($1,1,c)};exit}
```

version 2, 144 bytes: extra complex output ( each lines looking like: ['c']  ['c', 'a']  ['c', 'a', 't'] )

```
{s=length($1);for(c=1;c<=s;c++)for(n=1;n<=c*5;n++){printf"[";for(i=1;i<=c;i++)printf("%s'%s'",(i>1)?", ":"",substr($1,i,1));printf("]\n")};exit}
```

Thanks to the exit, this processes only the first line entered on stdin.
Getting rid of it also processes multiple lines, one by one, stacking the towers together (and savig 5 bytes).

The default is the above, with only 1 tower (and only the first input line processed)

Comment: @whalalalalalala-chen : I try to respect the output given in the question... as it is unclear what output would be acceptable otherwise (if it could be : c ca  cat, without the '[' ']' and "'" , then the answer can be much shorter!)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 96 bytes

```pascal
var s:string;i,j:word;begin read(s);for i:=1to length(s)do for j:=1to i*5do writeln(s[1..i])end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc0xDoMwDADAr3gE1EZi6JKIP3SvOgRiUqPIQXYEzw9Q1ltu9Tr59JzXqdbNC6jVIsTR0WOxe5bgRozEIOhDo62bswDZoS8ZEnIsvxNDhouXm6l7nbALFUzc6Kc3hr4tcjC1vv/bAQ)

<sub>Longer than Java :(</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [brainf**k](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) <s>93</s> <s>81</s> 76 bytes

```
++++++++++>+>>,[[<]<[<<+<+++++[>>>>>[.>]<[<]<<.<<-]>>>-]<<[->>+<<]>>+>>[>],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYs5CoBAEARzX2G@xwuajv3DMIEniIsLC@Lzx9HAiqoLemrjfm7XfJiFHwYyikAhQMDXhC@S@UYFMpDUS3KXRAbApx@FGtU6G9ZSan/XVpYH)

Saved 12 bytes by removing a never-used empty cell. Saved another 5 bytes due to the help of Dorian (thanks!). Did not update the "How it works" section.

### How it works

```
[-][ https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170872/tower-of-strings ]
[-][ -------------------------------------------------------------------- ]
[-][ Variables                                                            ]
[-][ p0: temp0                                                            ]
[-][ p1: temp1                                                            ]
[-][ p2: {LF}                                                             ]
[-][ p3: n input characters                                               ]
[-][ p4: zero                                                             ]
[-][ p5... inputs                                                         ]


p0    [-]
p1  > [-]
p2  > ++++++++++
p3  > + 
p4  > [-]
p5  > ,   # read input
      [   # open loop 
p4      [<] # go back to p4
p3       <
## loop current number of inputs
         [ 
p2         <
p1         < + # copy p3 to p1
p0         < +++++ # use p0 to count to 5
          [
p1         >
p2         > 
p3         >
p4         >
p5         >
           [ ## output all until empty
             . >
           ] <
p4         [<] #back to p4
p3         <
p2         < . #output {LF}
p1         < 
p0         <-
          ]
p1         >
p2         > 
p3         > -
         ]
## copy p1 back to p3
p2       <
p1       <
         [ -
p2         >
p3         > +
p2         <
p1         <
         ]
p2        >
p3        > + # increase p3
p4        >
next     >[>] ,  # read next character
      ]
```

Shorter than Java ;-)

Comment: Hi and welcome to codegolf. You can remove the starting `>>`. Tio can handle negative indexes. And you can remove the `[-]`, since that cell is already 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 10 bytes

```
@L:OvL5*:"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/Bx8q/zMdUy0rp////SsmJJUoA)

```
                   \ Implicit: Input on stack, as character codes
@                  \ Reverse stack
 L:                \ length(stack) times do:
   Ov              \   Move TOS to auxiliary stack
     L5*:          \   5 * length(auxiliary stack) times do:
         "         \     Print the auxiliary stack as a string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 89 bytes

Without LINQ.

```cs
x=>{int i=0;while(i++<x.Length)for(var j=0;j++<i*5;)Console.WriteLine(x.Substring(0,i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9C8IwFEX3/oqHU@JHcXGKLYirguDgnKaxfTVNJHnVSulvr1EHucO53ANXhZVyXk9dQFvB@RVItyJRRoYAJ@8qL9shAbh3hUEFgSRFPByWcJRoGR@SnSJ0dhvIx4ccSsimPssHtASYrcWzRqMZLhbbPj1oW1HNr86zh/TQRN1EgfON4HtngzM6vXgkfUCrWZ@eu@J3y9ZL5FyMk0hKNqtn/Esl6d9q3Rqnbp9hjJne)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 70 bytes

If it's okay to print the strings like h he hel hell hello then this is a valid answer. Otherwise, I might need to add more code to make the square brackets, quotes and commas.

```php
for(;$x<strlen($argn);)echo str_repeat(substr($argn,0,++$x)."
",5*$x);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVKmyKS4pyUvM0VBKL0vM0rTVTkzPyFYBi8UWpBamJJRrFpUlAHkRax0BHW1ulQlNPiUtJx1QLyLL@/z8jNScn//@//IKSzPy84v@6bgA)